# Разбираемся в Python

Tags: python, массивы, функции, изображения, numpy

Пытаюсь изучать Python и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Есть функция:

```
def preprocess(imgs):
    imgs_p = np.ndarray((imgs.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(imgs.shape[0]):
        imgs_p[i] = resize(imgs[i], (img_cols, img_rows), preserve_range=True)
    imgs_p = imgs_p[..., np.newaxis]
    return imgs_p
```

И есть ее вызов:

```
imgs_train       = np.load(os.path.join(npy_data_path, 'imgs_train.npy'))
imgs_train = preprocess(imgs_train)
imgs_train = imgs_train.astype('float32')
```

Заголовки:

```
import os
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.io import imsave
import numpy as np
```

Цель:

> Убрать ресайзинг изображенния, с соблюдением всех остальных
>   манипуляций и встроить одну функцию в другую

Мой код:

```
imgs_train       = np.load(os.path.join(npy_data_path, 'imgs_train.npy'))
imgs_mask_train  = np.load(os.path.join(npy_data_path, 'mask_train.npy'))

for i in range(imgs_train.shape[0]):
    imgs_train[i]      = resize(imgs_train[i]     , preserve_range=True)
    imgs_mask_train[i] = resize(imgs_mask_train[i], preserve_range=True)        
imgs_train      = imgs_train[..., np.newaxis]
imgs_mask_train = imgs_mask_train[..., np.newaxis]

imgs_train = imgs_train.astype('float32')
imgs_mask_train = imgs_mask_train.astype('float32')
```

Ошибка:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "train.py", line 113, in
 <module>
     train_and_predict()   File "train.py", line 48, in train_and_predict
     imgs_train[i]      = resize(imgs_train[i]     , preserve_range=True) TypeError: resize() missing 1 required positional
 argument: 'output_shape'
```

Спасибо за помощь!

*P.S. Изучаю Python где-то неделю, поэтому прошу тапками не кидаться...*

Comment: у вас там написано, что `resize()` не получил аргумент - подайте его на вход или перепишите функцию, удалив его и логику с ним связанную

Comment: @EugeneDennis это библиотечная функция, не надо её переписывать.

Comment: @EugeneDennis, я бы с удовольствием
Но эта обработка же, как я понял, не только ресайзит, но и
1) preserve_range=True - меняет формат цвета

Comment: 2) Добавляет еще одно измерение

Comment: imgs_train      = imgs_train[..., np.newaxis]

Comment: И пытаюсь тупо убрать требование разрешения изображения в данной функции

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG стоит потратить на изучение Python больше недели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [skimage.transform.resize()](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) вторым аргументом принимает размер изображения, а вы его не передаёте.

Comment: Так он неизвестен

Comment: А preserve_range=True что-то делает

Comment: Есть ли функция, которая делает только:

Comment: Whether to keep the original range of values. Otherwise, the input image is converted according to the conventions of img_as_float. Also see https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял ваш код, вы пытаетесь обучить ИНС (Искусственную Нейронную Сеть) для классификации картинок. На данном шаге изменяется размер картинки. Делается это потому что архитектура ИНС ожидает входную 3D или 4D матрицу **определенного размера**. Именно поэтому размер картинок на вход в ИНС задается жёстко ("hard coded"). ИНС не будет работать с матрицей неправильной размерности, поэтому если вы хотите отказаться от "ресайзинга" вам придется поменять архитектуру ИНС соответствующим образом.

NOTE: при увеличении картинки на входе резко возрастает число параметров, которые расчитывает ИНС при обучении и работе, поэтому вы должны быть готовы к кратному увеличению времени.

Comment: Да, вы правы
Но! Проблема в том, что ресайжу я картинки сразу (при парсинге)

Comment: Поэтому и не хочу прописывать их разрешение каждый

Comment: раз. А также хотелось бы понять, что делает preserve_range=True

Comment: И сделать так, чтоб просто не указывать разрешение картинок